# Getting filename (or path) from fstream

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

Can I get a file name or its path from a `fstream` object? I looked through the methods of `fstream` and didn't find anything close to it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The underlying file may have several names (if it has multiple hard links) or no name at all (if it represents an anonymous pipe, for instance).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, that is not possible, not at least in the Standard conformant implementation of the library.

The fstream class doesn't store the filename, and doesn't provide any function for retrieving it.

So one way to keep track of this information is to use `std::map` as:

```
std::map<std::fstream*, std::string> stream_file_table;

void f()
{
  //when you open a file, do this:
  std::fstream file("somefile.txt");

  stream_file_table[&file] = "somefile.txt"; //store the filename

  //..
  g(file);
}
void g(std::fstream & file)
{
    std::string filename = stream_file_table[&file]; //get the filename
    //...
}
```

Or, simply pass around the filename as well.

Comment: This looks alright, only you would need to say that the name has to be removed once the fstream objects get destroyed...

Comment: It is perfectly possible to be standard conformat *and* include a way to retrieve the filename used to open a file. That's called an extension.

Comment: @Clearer No-one said it'd be non-conforming then. The point is the Standard does not provide for it.

Comment: @bloody It says "not at least in the Standard conformant implementation" which makes it sound like having that feature would make it non conforming

Comment: Extensions are NOT part of the Standard. If you use such features, then your code is NOT standard conformant anymore. If you change your compiler, then your code may not compile as your new compiler might be missing the extension you're using in your code.

Answer (score 31):

you may also design a little class which inherits from `fstream` and behaves like a `fstream` but also stores its file name.

Comment: This also allows you to add a convenient constructor taking a `std::string`, which is required in C++11 but not usually present in C++03 implementations.

Comment: Or if reusability and/or extendability is of no concern, a simple struct storing a string and a file stream object.