# How to detect if ofstream is writing to /dev/null

Tags: c++, fstream

Is there any (simple) way to detect in `some_function()` if `ofs` is writing to `/dev/null` or not?

```
#include <fstream>

some_function(std::ofstream & ofs);

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("/dev/null");
    ofs << "lorem ipsum";

    some_function(ofs); // Testing in here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need that call to `ofs.close()`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a FILE\* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)

Comment: @Frank Not sure if that's a dupe.

Comment: Quick hack: check the size of `/dev/null` before and after the call ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: More likely, this one: [Getting filename (or path) from fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773391/getting-filename-or-path-from-fstream)

Comment: Are you asking whether you can test that the constructor did what you told it to do, or are you asking how to get back information that you've thrown away? If writing to /dev/null means something special, keep a note that that's what you're doing.

Comment: With C++ standard library, you *cannot* do that. Targeting a specific platform, you can use different tricks. (E.g. if you know you have just one file open, you can query the Linux /proc and get the file open by your process). Anyway if you reach the "implementation" level you can do that using some platform dependent call.

Comment: What are you trying to solve here?  Is your question academic, or are you trying to solve a specific issue?

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any (simple) way to detect in `some_function(std::ofstream ofs)` if `ofs` is writing to `/dev/null` or not?

No, there isn't.

The fact that you are looking for a way to get that information indicates to me that `some_function` has branching code depending on whether you are writing to `/dev/null` or not.

You can address that problem by adding another argument to the function and let the client code provide that information to you.

```
void some_function(std::ofstream& ofs, bool isDevNull);
```

and use it as:

```
std::ofstream ofs ("/dev/null", std::ofstream::out);
ofs << "lorem ipsum";
some_function(ofs, true);
```

Comment: I agree.  Separation of concerns.

Comment: You can do that or create a wrapper class, which stores directory info used to open stream. This way it isn't tied to Dev, ex: production env.

Answer (score 1):

from `std::ofstream`, no.

From a `FILE*`, yes but it's not portable.

Here's a version for linux:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct file_closer
{
    void operator()(FILE*p) const noexcept
    {
        if (p)
            fclose(p);
    }
};

auto open_write(const char* path) -> std::unique_ptr<FILE, file_closer>
{
    auto result = std::unique_ptr<FILE, file_closer>(fopen(path, "w"));

    if (!result.get())
        throw std::runtime_error("not opened");
    return result;
}

size_t do_readlink(const char* path, char* buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    auto len = readlink(path, buffer, buflen);
    if (len < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to read link");
    return size_t(len);
}

bool is_dev_null(FILE* fp)
{
    int fd = fileno(fp);
    std::ostringstream procpath;
    procpath << "/proc/self/fd/" << fd;
    auto spath = procpath.str(); 

    size_t bufs = 1024;
    std::string path(bufs, ' ');
    auto len = do_readlink(spath.c_str(), &path[0], bufs);
    while(len > bufs)
    {
        bufs = len;
        path.resize(bufs);
        len = do_readlink(spath.c_str(), &path[0], bufs);
    }

    path.resize(len);
    return path == "/dev/null";
}

int main()
{
    auto fp = open_write("/dev/null");
    std::cout << is_dev_null(fp.get());
}
```